# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Chrome. Loading JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wrote script, that gets data from json file. It works correct in Firefox, but in Chrome is error:

> OPTIONS file:///home/[...]/tilemaps/testmap.json Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery.js:6
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/[...]/tilemaps/testmap.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This is code:

```
function newTileMapFromJSON(src) {
    var mymap;
    $.getJSON(src, function(data) {
        mymap = data;
        //console.log(mymap);
        console.log("Mapa 0, 0 : " + mymap.layers[0].data[0]);
        var wOfArray = mymap.layers[0].width;
        var hOfArray = mymap.layers[0].height;
        var mapArr = [];
        var imAt = 2;
        for (var x = 0; x < wOfArray; x++) {
            for (var y = 0; y < hOfArray; y++) {
                console.log("imAt" + imAt + " x: " + x);
                mapArr[x][y] = mymap.layers[0].data[imAt];
                imAt++;
            }
        }
        console.log("mapArr: " + mapArr);
    });
}

newTileMapFromJSON("tilemaps/testmap.json");
```

Why it doesn't work? Why it works on Firefox but not on Chrome.
PS: In Firefox, for loop works only once. But it should work 25x25 times :/

Comment: If I remember correctly, Chrome doesn't like pulling files from local servers.

Comment: But when I put it on server it will work? If yes, it's ok. I'll work on server

Answer (score 2):

file:/// is considered inherently dangerous. If you want chrome to allow XHR retrievals when running from file rather than from a localhost server (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, etc) then you're going to have to start Chrome with the flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`